# is there a mtrace with full stack trace? or can it be simply modified to have this functionality?

Tags: c++, memory-management, profiling, mtrace

During analysis mem consumption of huge app I use mtrace from glibc. But the problem is it gives just source of malloc call, but not full stack trace. So if I use malloc in method that is used in many places I have only one indistinguishable source of malloc reported. Another problem is standard c library and generic objects like CSimpleArray. I only know that somebody used huge array, but don't know who exactly.

So I thought I need full stack trace to know who exactly used malloc. Do you know if such a variant of mtrace exist? or can it be simply modified to do that?

Just a remark: my mtrace.out log contains 300k lines, after processing it with mtrace script it has 10k entries. It is anough for me if I localize only 10% biggest chunks.